# I want to extend an existing dictionary with a for loop through a list

Tags: python

I've simplified my code to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I have a list of something, and in that list are also my keys to a dictionary. I'm trying to do a for loop that takes each element in the list, runs a function on that element, and then I want to extend my dictionary with what returned from the function. What am I doing wrong here?

```
student_list = ['Whitney', 'Jason']
first_dict = {'Whitney':'Math', "Jason":"Biology"}

def schedule(student):
    B = 'Science'
    C = 'Social Studies'
    D = 'Gym'
    E = 'Lunch'

for student in student_list:
    schedule(student)
    first_dict[student].append([B, C, D, E])
```

my error is: `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Though I'm sure I'm doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to append your values to a string, which is something you cannot do. Change the values in `first_dict` from strings to lists (e.g. `'Math'` to `['Math']`) and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks! I also moved my .append into the function instead of the for loop, but I end up with this:  ```{'Jason': ['Biology', ['Science', 'Social Studies', 'Gym', 'Lunch']], 'Whitney': ['Math', ['Science', 'Social Studies', 'Gym', 'Lunch']]} ``` . Is there a way to make it so that math and all of the other subjects are in the same list?

Comment: Also, you should define variables `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` outside the method `schedule`. Because right now it's only local to the `schedule` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
student_list = ['Whitney', 'Jason']
first_dict = {'Whitney':['Math'], "Jason":["Biology"]}

def schedule(student):
    B = 'Science'
    C = 'Social Studies'
    D = 'Gym'
    E = 'Lunch'
    first_dict[student].extend([B, C, D, E])

for student in student_list:
    schedule(student)
```